# Number of integer solutions to linear equation/inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

If I am given an equation in the form of $ax+by=c$, I understand there is an algorithm to find solutions, but is there a way to find the number of all the integer solutions in a speedy method? Can this method be expanded to find the number of integer solutions to $ax+by < c$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by the solutions to $ax+by$? Do you mean the solutions to $ax+by=c_0$ for fixed $c_0$?

Comment: The rest was cut off, it was corrected.

Comment: There are infinitely many integer solutions of ax + by < c. Probably, you mean positive integer solutions.